# If $U \subseteq V$, then $V^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

So I'm trying to show that if $U \subseteq V$, then $V^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$, where ${}^\perp$ denotes orthogonal complement.

I started by assuming a vector $v \in V^\perp$, so $\langle v,w \rangle = 0$ for all $w \in V$.

So if $w$ happens to be inside $U$, it means that $\langle v,w \rangle = 0$ for all $w \in U$ and thus $v$ is inside $U^\perp$.

But what about the other case? i.e. when $w$ is inside $V$ but outside $U$? How can I proceed then?

Thank you

Comment: Please use MathJax. These symbols are not rendering on my browser.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip Please check now, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already shown all that needs to be shown. If $w$ is not in $U$, then whether $\langle v,w \rangle = 0$ or not is irrelevant for determining whether $v \in U^\perp$.

In other words, $v \in U^\perp$ means $\forall w. w \in U \Rightarrow \langle v,w \rangle = 0$, so it does not matter what happens when $w \notin U$.

---

Let's see if I can write out a proof as explanatory as I can.

We want to show that $V^\perp \subseteq U^\perp$. So, given any $w \in V^\perp$, we need to show that $w \in U^\perp$. We know that $\langle w,v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$, by definition of $V^\perp$.

Now $w \in U^\perp$ means that for all $u \in U$, $\langle w,u \rangle = 0$. To show this, suppose we are given $u \in U$. Since $U \subseteq V$, we have $u \in V$. Then $\langle w,u \rangle = 0$, because $w \in V^\perp$ and $u \in V$.

---

In general, if $U \subseteq V$, then any statement that is true for all elements of $V$ is automatically true for all elements of $U$. So if $\langle w,v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$, then $\langle w,u \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in U$, simply because $V$ contains $U$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The final goal is to prove that V⊥ ⊆ U⊥. So we need to show that for all vectors in V⊥, they are in U⊥ too right? If I'm taking only the subset of vectors that are orthogonal to the vectors in U, it won't suffice to support the claim right? or I'm missing something?

Comment: That's the thing, any vector that's orthogonal to all vectors in $V$ is *a fortiori* orthogonal to all vectors in $U$, because $V$ contains $U$. I have edited my answer with a proof that will hopefully give a clear idea of what's happening.

Comment: If you want to "feel" the phenomenon, the bigger set of equations you have, the smaller the set of solutions is. Then, the set of defining eqs of $V^\perp$ is $(\langle v,x \rangle = 0)_{v\in V}$ and the one of $U^\perp$ is $(\langle v,x \rangle = 0)_{v\in U}$ (less eqs).