# Prove $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{S} \text{ iff } \mathcal{S}^{\perp} \subseteq R^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

Solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947464/if-u-subseteq-v-then-v-perp-subseteq-u-perp) for part of the question.

Question: Let $\mathcal{R}, \mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (EDIT), where $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{S}$ are subspaces. Then prove that $\mathcal{R} \subseteq S$ *iff* $\mathcal{S}^{\perp} \subseteq \mathcal{R}^{\perp}$ where the '$^\perp$' means the orthgonal complement.

Just for the sake of of confirming that I know how to do the first part given in the link, I will do it as well.

EDIT: I updated it to add in the '$\forall$' statement.

*Proof*. We show '$\Rightarrow$' first. Suppose we take any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{R}$. This implies $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S}$. Let $\mathbf{y} \in S^{\perp}$. Note, by the orthogonal complement definition, we have that $\langle\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle = 0; \forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{R} (\text{and hence}, \forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{S}) \implies \mathbf{y} \in\mathcal{R}^{\perp}$.

We show '$\Leftarrow$' now. Suppose we take any $\mathbf{x} \in S^{\perp} \implies \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{R}^{\perp}$. Let $\mathbf{y} \in \mathcal{R}$. Note, by the orthogonal complement definition, we have that $\langle \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}\rangle = 0; \forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{S}^{\perp} (\text{and hence}, \forall\mathbf{x}\in\mathcal{R}^{\perp}) \implies \mathbf{y} \in \mathcal{S}$.

Is this a fine proof?

Comment: I don't think the proof works.  For example on $\Rightarrow$, you begin by assuming $y \in S^{\perp}$ and you need to show $y \in R^{\perp}$.  You never actually show this.  An element is in $R^{\perp}$ if and only if its pairing with EVERY element of $R$ is $0$.  It's not clear how you're making use of this.

Comment: The converse, that $S^{\perp} \subseteq R^{\perp}$ implies $R \subseteq S$, is actually false if you only assume that $R$ and $S$ are subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: What are $\mathcal{R}$ and $\mathcal{S}$? Are they subspaces? The question seems to say they are simply subsets... in this case, the statement would be wrong. Since $\mathcal{R}^\perp = Span(\mathcal{R})^\perp$, you could choose $\mathcal{S}=\{v\}$ where $v$ is any non zero vector and $\mathcal{R}=Span(\{v\})$.

Comment: You're close, but be careful: $\vec{y} \in S^\perp$ means that $\langle \vec{x}, \vec{y} \rangle = 0$ for *every* $\vec{x} \in S$, not just for some particular $\vec{x}$.

Comment: I see @D_S, Then Connor_Harris's remark is what I would need to say, that for ALL $\mathbb{x}$. This is ineeded what I was thinking of as well when you made that remark :)

Comment: @Taladris, they are subspaces, my apologies for the vagueness.